# python-pptx format and alignment lost for specific tables and their headers

Tags: python, replace, formatting, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to automate the powerpoint find and replace using a python code.

With the help of multiple SO posts, I managed to get to the below piece of code which does the replacement of keywords by looping through all slides in a PPT. The issue below happens only for certain tables and rest of the tables work fine (no issues in formatting, font size, color etc) but certain tables have the below 3 issues (am not sure why)

```
slides = [slide for slide in ip_ppt.slides]
shapes = []
for slide in slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        shapes.append(shape)

def replace_text(replacements:dict,shapes:list):
    """Takes dict of {match: replacement, ... } and replaces all matches.
    Currently not implemented for charts or graphics.
    """
    for shape in shapes:
        for match, replacement in replacements.items():
            if shape.has_text_frame:
                if (shape.text.find(match)) != -1:
                    text_frame = shape.text_frame
                    for paragraph in text_frame.paragraphs:
                        for run in paragraph.runs:
                            cur_text = run.text
                            new_text = cur_text.replace(str(match), str(replacement))
                            run.text = new_text
            if shape.has_table:
                for row in shape.table.rows:
                    for cell in row.cells:
                        if match in cell.text:
                            new_text = cell.text.replace(match, replacement)
                            cell.text = new_text


replace_text({'FY1920':'FY20/21'},shapes)
replace_text({'FY2021':'FY21/22'},shapes)
replace_text({'FY2122':'FY22/23'},shapes)
```

While this works correctly for 90% of the cases, I do encounter few scenarios like below. Is there anyway to identify these tables by name and make those changes?

a) Only for Certain table column headers, font color is changed (after replacement)

[image]

b) Only for Certain tables, overlap issue occurs (after replacement) (because they become big in size) shown below

[image]

c) Only for Certain tables, column headers font size and alignment differs shown below

[image]

How can I avoid the above 3 scenarios from happening?

Ideally, the code above isn't supposed to cause these issues but now that it has done, I am looking for some simple way to fix these issues (doesn't have to be efficient or elegant).

Is there anyway to tell/enforce the code (during for loop) explicitly to keep the same font color, font size, font alignment etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I managed to solve this by drilling down to run level and reassigning the font size and name to my text. So, format is retained

Please find my updated code for table section

```
           if shape.has_table:
                for row in shape.table.rows:
                    for cell in row.cells:
                        paras = cell.text_frame.paragraphs
                        for para in paras:
                            #print(para.text)
                            for run in para.runs:
                                if match in run.text:
                                    new_text = run.text.replace(str(match), str(replacement))
                                    fn = run.font.name
                                    fz = run.font.size 
                                    run.text = new_text
                                    run.font.name = fn
                                    run.font.size = fz
```

Answer (score 1):

Without getting my hands on your exact Powerpoint, it's hard for me to know that this will work for you. But, this is a function I have been using to automate Powerpoints lately, and I haven't had formatting issues with it, yet.

```
def search_and_replace(search_str, repl_str, input, output):
    '''search and replace text in PowerPoint while preserving formatting
        search_str: the string in the template
        repl_str: the string replacing the search_str
        input: the powerpoint file name
        output: the save name for the updated file'''

    from pptx import Presentation
    prs = Presentation(input)
    for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if shape.has_text_frame:
                if(shape.text.find(search_str))!=-1:
                    text_frame = shape.text_frame
                    cur_text = text_frame.text
                    new_text = cur_text.replace(str(search_str), str(repl_str))
                    text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].text = new_text
    prs.save(output)
```

If you use this, please backup your file first, as this function replaces the text and then saves the file as the given filename. Let me know how it works for you!

Comment: Am going through the code. I tried this but this doesn't replace the table headers etc?

Comment: Maybe the table headers behave in a different way than the rest of the text. Are you putting the text you want to replace in the search_str argument, and the new text in the repl_str argument, and putting the correct file as the input and output? The file must be closed for it to work, as aside note.

Comment: Do you know how can we extract table cell properties like font color, font size and cell alignment etc?

Comment: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html
This may be a useful resource for properties of text-related objects. Unfortunately I've only tested this on header text and body/paragraph text, not on tables.

Comment: Not to be a killjoy but doesn't this flatten all the runs?